# Why do I give correct positional arguments but still get back a error message?

Tags: python

I've been having an issue with the following code:

```
class User:

def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile):
    self.profile = profile
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name`
    self.profile['first_name'] = first_name
    self.profile['last_name'] = last_name

def query(self, key):
    value = self.profile[key]
    print('Here is the result:' + '\n\t' + str(value))


class UserVip(User):
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile):
    super().__init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile)


ron_weasley = UserVip('ron', 'weasley', 
                  age=17,`enter code here
                  school='hogwarts'
                  )
```

And when I ran it，I got back this error message

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

But the '**profile'can recieve any number of arguments,can't it?Then I checked the arguments,and tried like this

```
ron_weasley = UserVip('ron', 'weasley', 
                      school='hogwarts'
                      )
```

It stil went wrong.I had also tried some other means and  been searching for a long time on net. But no use. Do I misundersand the **init**(),the inherit or the '**(dict)'?Please help or try to give some ideas how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of `super`, you can also `classname` in your code.

For example, call parent class `__init__` using below code

`User.__init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile)`

Hope it solves your problem. !

Comment: using classname, you are just calling that class's method and passing all arguments including self. So it works as it got all the arguments it needed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to repeat the `self` argument in calling parent `__init__`

Ie should be: 
`super().__init__(first_name, last_name, **profile)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't have used `self` in `super().__init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile)`.
Here is a code which is working :

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile):
        self.profile = profile
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.profile['first_name'] = first_name
        self.profile['last_name'] = last_name

    def query(self, key):
        value = self.profile[key]
        print('Here is the result:' + '\n\t' + str(value))


class UserVip(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, **profile)


ron_weasley = UserVip('ron', 'weasley', age=17, school='hogwarts')
ron_weasley.query('age')
```

Answer (score -1):

First you indentation is wrong for `__init__` of UserVip class.

Second, you should use `User` instead of `super()` for UserVip's super class constructor. Or you can remove self from the argument

Following code works for me.

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile):
        self.profile = profile
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.profile['first_name'] = first_name
        self.profile['last_name'] = last_name

    def query(self, key):
        value = self.profile[key]
        print('Here is the result:' + '\n\t' + str(value))


class UserVip(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile):
        User.__init__(self, first_name, last_name, **profile)


ron_weasley = UserVip('ron', 'weasley', age=17,school='hogwarts')
```